# Info about added layer from map.on(layeradd) event in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, layers

I added this to my leaflet.js:

```
   map.on("layeradd", function(evt) {
      myLocalName = "on layeradd";
      console.log(myLocalName, evt);
   });
```

I have to know which layer has been added, because I need special code for some layers. Same for `layerremove` event later. I could not get any info in `evt` about the added layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the Leaflet docs at https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layerevent, you'll see that event processing function parameter `evt` has property `evt.layer`, which is created layer object.

If you want to identify the layer, you can use some custom option, let's say `myLayerId`, when creating layer, for example:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  myLayerId: 1
}).addTo(map);
```

You can then identify layer in event processing function simply be refering to it by `evt.layer.options.myLayerId`:

```
map.on('layeradd', function(evt) {
  console.log('Layer added: ', evt.layer.options.myLayerId);
});
```

Comment: To be honest, i forgot to tell you, that i'm not using the standard layer control of leaflet, but a layer tree plugin (https://github.com/bambrikii/leaflet-layer-tree-plugin). The return values of the event is NOT the new layer, but some other stuff. This plugin was working fine the beginning of my project, but from week to week i'm having more problems using this. Wrote some workarounds too, but this problem will force me to get rid of it right now.

Thanks

walter

If you like, look at https://wambachers-osm.website/Emergency.html (Data only for Germany/Austria & Switzerland)

Comment: I now tried also with leaflet-layer-tree plugin and it worked OK for me.